# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "...lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so"

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, customtkinter

I'm trying to run a simple program to verify the customtkinter package installation on a raspberry pi 4b.

I've installed the packages and tested it with the simple program found [the offical customtkinter website](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/).

```
import customtkinter

def button_callback():
    print("button clicked")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x150")

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="my button", command=button_callback)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

app.mainloop()
```

The program bombs, giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsc/Desktop/Feeder/simple.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tsc/Desktop/Feeder/customtkinter/windows/ctk_tk.py", line 41, in __init__
    TK_CLASS.__init__(self, **pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self._valid_tk_constructor_arguments))
  File "/home/tsc/feed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkinterDnD/tk.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.TkDnDVersion = _init_tkdnd(self)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tsc/feed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkinterDnD/tk.py", line 28, in _init_tkdnd
    TkDnDVersion = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'tkdnd')
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/home/tsc/feed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so": /home/tsc/feed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've ran this same code on my mac, and it runs just fine.

Here's the pi's specs:

```
pi 4b with the latest Raspberry Pi OS with desktop:
Release date: October 10th 2023
System: 64-bit
Kernel version: 6.1
Debian version: 12 (bookworm)
```

I used pip list to get the installed packages on the mac, and used that to install the same packages on the pi.

```
(feed) tsc@tsc:~/Desktop/Feeder $ pip list
Package       Version
------------- ---------
certifi       2023.7.22
configparser  6.0.0
customtkinter 5.2.1
darkdetect    0.8.0
Pillow        10.1.0
pip           23.0.1
python-tkdnd  0.2.1
pyusb         1.2.1
setuptools    66.1.1
tk            0.1.0
tkinterdnd2   0.3.0
ttkwidgets    0.13.0
```

Here's whats on the mac.

```
r-iMac:Feeder r$ pip list
Package       Version
------------- ----------
certifi       2020.4.5.2
configparser  6.0.0
customtkinter 5.2.0
darkdetect    0.8.0
Pillow        10.0.0
pip           23.2.1
python-tkdnd  0.2.1
pyusb         1.2.1
setuptools    41.2.0
tk            0.1.0
tkinterdnd2   0.3.0
ttkwidgets    0.13.0
```

I reinstalled the pi OS, and created several venv's, reinstalling all the packages from scratch and I still get the same error.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The website are waiting for this Cross-Compiler Toolchain for Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. It is too early.

Comment: I just got the exact same error using Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye.  Couldn't be the Cross-Compiler Toolchain if it's happening on the previous OS.

Comment: The customtkinter could wait for update. Be patient and wait for the website update.

Comment: Ok, genuinely confused now.  So I know can't use customtkinter on any OS if it's a fresh install?  Is there anyway to get past this?  How long for the website to be "updated"?  Sorry to ask so many questions, but this project is my top priority at the moment.

Comment: No you can't refresh it. You may want to ask question. https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/